Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input in react
I'm trying to send a new product data to my server and i get this err
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
while the object that i've entered in JSON is not empty
const newProductsInfos = {
  title: newProductTitle,
  price: newProductPrice,
  count: newProductCount,
  img: newProductImg,
  popularity: newProductPopularity,
  sale: newProductSale,
  colors: newProductColors,
};
const addNewProduct = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/products`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newProductsInfos),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((resullt) => {
      console.log(resullt);
    });
};

i have logged the response of json and its
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/products', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} body : ReadableStream bodyUsed : false headers : Headers {} ok : true redirected : false status : 200 statusText : "OK" type : "cors" url : "http://localhost:8000/api/products" [[Prototype]] : Response

The log result you're showing looks like a Response object but that's not possible with the code shown. Use your browser's dev-tools Network panel to easily inspect the response body. Whatever it is, it is not JSON so res.json() will fail

hard to say what the exact issue is with the given information. Maybe the request itself doesn't provide a valid json. for debugging purposes i would test the error parameter for the fetch (e.g.  (error) => console.error(error)) or test the results with out parsing the data to json, just collecting the text and console.log to check if the expected results match the collected ones. E.g. fetch(...).then((r)=>r.text()).then((r)=>console.log(r))

@Phil the log result is provided when i used console.log(res) instead of res.json() to see if the resposne JSON is or not.

@JWittmeyer i've tried r.text and the log result is "empty string" . what can cause that?

@MohammadAskari this means your endpoint doesn't return any text "" (or the text "empty string" not sure from your comment). In your question the console log shows a body : ReadableStream. The readable stream gets "read" through the text() call. If your body doesn't contain any data it's most likely the backend. Further steps to understand the issue would imo include opening the Network tab in the browser of your choice & check the requests payload (what you send) and Response (what the server sends back). If the server doesn't send anything you can't parse the results

Why is result spelt wrong?
"resullt"
also, i thought keys were meant to look like this:
"employer" : "Brad"


Spelling aside, it's still correct syntax and would not cause a problem

JSON.stringify adds the quotes around the keys.  If your suggestion is that the JavaScript dict newProductsInfos is missing quotes, that is not the problem and a wrong answer.
